# Best approach to stream multiple types with GRPC

Tags: java, python, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a server that passes messages to a client. The messages are of different types and the server has a generic `handleMessage` and `passMessage` method for the clients.

Now I intend to adapt this and use GRPC for it. I know I could expose all methods of the server by defining services in my `.proto` file. But is there also a way to:

- Stream
- heterogenous types
- with one RPC call
- using GRPC

There is `oneof` which allows me to set a message that has only one of the properties set. I could have a `MessageContainer` that is `oneof` and all my message types are included in this container. Now the container only has one of the types and I would only need to write one

```
service {
   rpc messageHandler(ClientInfo)  returns (stream MessageContainer)
}
```

This way, the server could stream multiple types to the client through one unique interface. Does this make sense? Or is it better to have all methods exposed individually?

**UPDATE**

I found [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/grpc-io/sVqORAROElI) which argues `oneof` would be the way to go. I'd like that obviously as it avoids me having to create potentially dozens of services and stubs. It would also help to make sure it's a FIFO setup instead of multiplexing several streams and not being sure which message came first. But it *feels* dirty for some reason.

Comment: I think your update asks more questions than it answers. If your use case encompasses potentially dozens of "kinds of things that clients might ask servers to do", then why isn't "potentially dozens of RPC method definitions" the solution? And share more about your RPC method semantics that motivates wanting "a FIFO setup" and as much order as possible? Generally there's efficiency to be found in reordering so distributed systems are implemented with as little ordering as their use cases allow.

Comment: well, in my use case, the server generates a bunch of messages of all sorts of types and pushes them to clients. Now I could create a RPC endpoint for each type and allow the client to subscribe to each type or I just send them all down the same pipe but with different envelopes. The FIFO would help as in my case it's a round based game simulation and those messages of each round are best not be shuffled too much.

Comment: Yes, in this case it sounds like one logical RPC and the ordering of the messages sounds like exactly what's needed. What would be worth splitting up into different RPCs would be the messages associated with different instances of the same game or different instances of different games - those messages clearly need not have order maintained.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this makes sense (and what you are calling `MessageContainer` is best understood as a [sum type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_type)).

... but it is still better to define different methods when you can ("better" here means "more idiomatic, more readable by future maintainers of your system, and better able to be changed in the future when method semantics need to change").

The question of whether to express your service as a single RPC method returning a sum type or as multiple RPC methods comes down to whether or not the particular addend type that will be used can be known at RPC invocation time. Is it the case that when you set `request.my_type_determining_field` to `5` that the stream transmitted by the server always consists of `MessageContainer` messages that have their `oneof` set to a `MyFifthKindOfParticularMessage` instance? If so then you should probably just write a separate RPC method that returns a stream of `MyFifthKindOfParticularMessage` messages. If, however, it is the case that at RPC invocation time you *don't* know with certainty what the used addend types of the messages transmitted from the server will be (and "messages with different addend types in the same stream" is a sub-use-case of this), then I don't think it's possible for your service to be factored into different RPCs and the right thing for you to do is have one RPC method that returns a stream of a sum type.